# Angular click on parent div doesn't triggers on all child divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I have ng-click event on parent DIV, which calls function. I want this event to be triggered only if the parent div is clicked, not if the child div is clicked. So, if the area clicked inside parent covers child div, event should not trigger. Now, click on div2 triggers event.

My example is [here on code pen](http://codepen.io/FrenkyB/pen/pbVXXY)

Html structure:

```
<div id="div1" class="div1" ng-app="appModule" ng-controller="appController" ng-click="test();">
  <div id="div2" class="div2">
  </div>
</div>
```

There is div1 (parent div) and div2 inside this div (child div). I've put ng-click on parent div, because I need it to be triggered everywhere on the parent, only on the div2 not. How to achieve this with angular?

Comment: This is the problem of JavaScript Event Bubbling.

Comment: Add a click listener on child element and use stopPropogation to stop event bubbling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check if the `target` element and `currentTarget` is same

HTML

```
<div id="div1" class="div1" ng-app="appModule" ng-controller="appController" ng-click="test($event);"> // Passing event object
  // Rest of code
</div>
```

JS

```
$scope.test = function(e) {
  if (e.target == e.currentTarget) {  // checking if target and currentTarget is same
    alert("test!");
  } else {
    //Rest of code

  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `$event.target` to validate which element is clicked. then execute the operation. Here in example, I have used `id` property

```
<div id="div1" class="div1" ng-app="appModule" ng-controller="appController" ng-click="test($event);">
  <div id="div2" class="div2">
  </div>
</div>
```

*Script*

```
$scope.test = function(event) {
    if (event.target.id == 'div1') {
        alert("test!");
    }
}
```

[DEMO](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/oLdKjk)

Answer (score 1):

You can use ng-click="$event.stopPropagation()" to achieve this.If u do this , even if you click on a child element , the event doesnt propagate to Parent element.

```
<div id="div1" class="div1" ng-app="appModule" ng-controller="appController" ng-click="test();">
<div id="div2" ng-click="$event.stopPropagation()" class="div2">
  </div>
</div>
```